# Does it make sense to create a js class in a reactJS project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class

I would like to have your opinion on the following.

Does it make sense to create and use a « pure » javascript class inside of a reactJS project ? 
I mean for exemple I want to create let say a character class in a game (with methods affecting his state, health etc…). But I don’t especially want to have a visual component showing my character.  I could separate all methods with different buttons etc, but then all my methods would be in different places.

Im basically wondering if it makes sense to think that way with a reactJS project or if I should just rethink the whole thing in a more « react » way?

Comment: What you're describing means that a state is stored as class instance. It generally doesn't make sense because React encourages functional approach and plain objects for state. Using classes without knowing all consequences may result in awkward situations regarding app design in future. This also won't play well with Redux if you're serious about state management.

Comment: @estus yes i see what you mean. Indeed if i create a class it's going to be tricky (or not really clean?) to link my class and my state (I am using redux). 
So i should maybe think about making my reducer in a way that he will have the methods that my class would have had. Would it make more sense ?

Comment: If you're already using Redux then I guess there's nothing to think about, it promotes immutability, this doesn't work well with OOP. Yes, class methods will be transformed to separate functions in this case - reducers or else.